# Avoid inputting a file multiple times

Tags: macros, revision-control, input

I have a revision string automatically saved to a file VERSION (it is the output of `git describe` and usually looks like v2.2-19-g0a51c27), and define a command

```
\newcommand*\fileversion{\input{VERSION}}
```

However, each time the command is used, the file is read once. So if I put the command on every page, VERSION will be read many times (= number of pages).

Currently I use savebox to avoid this problem but unfortunately this can not pick up the surrounding formatting style, for example, if surrounding text is in footnotesize, the savebox still uses normal size.

I also tried `\edef\fileversion{\input{VERSION}}` but somehow TeX gave me 'stack limit' error.

So my question is how to define a command that expands to the contents of VERSION and not \input{VERSION}.

Comment: We probably need some detail on the nature of the `VERSION` file

Comment: Added. It is from `git describe`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution in plain tex could be like this (assuming a one-line file)

```
\newread\versionread
\immediate\openin\versionread = VERSION
\immediate\read\versionread to \fileversion
\immediate\closein\versionread
```

A (much) sneakier definition of \fileversion is also possible if you are using the etex extensions (which is probably true these days):

```
\makeatletter
{\everyeof{\noexpand}\xdef\fileversion{\@@input VERSION }}
\makeatother
```

Comment: `\read`'s are always `\immediate`, no?

Comment: Thanks for this. Another workaround that I have in mind is to output '\gdef\fileversion{xxxxxxx}' to VERSION so that I can use \input{VERSION} directly.

Comment: I was assuming that `VERSION` is 'externally generated' and so we should try to work with it 'as is'.

Comment: yeah, that would be my preference too.

Comment: @taco: may it be possible to explain the second solution a bit more? I have been staring at the e-TeX manual but could not understand how it works. Thanks.

Comment: At the end of a reading a file you get an EOF (end of file) marker. If you try the example without e-TeX then this will lead to errors during the `\xdef`. The `\everyeof` command inserts the `\noexpand` primitive, which prevents an error. `\@@input` is the raw TeX `\input` primitive renamed by LaTeX2e.

Comment: @Joseph: yes, \read is immediate, I keep forgetting that. Also, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on what Taco has just posted, I'd go for

```
\newcommand*\fileversion{%
  \newread\myread
  \openin\myread=VERSION 
  \read\myread to \fileversion
  \closein\myread
  \fileversion
}
```

as this will automatically redefine itself and print the version on first use.

Comment: But the first time you call this macro, it is not expandable, and that gave me trouble in my test file ;)

Comment: why is the last `\fileversion` needed?

Comment: I see. That makes sure the first time also outputs something.

Comment: Taco, I'd also be worrying about that (LaTeX3 'clear declaration of expandable functions' and everything). Not sure there is a solution unless you read the file in the preamble.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure you're using LuaTeX :)

```
\edef\fileversion{%
  \directlua{
    local f = io.open('VERSION')
    tex.print(f:read())
    f:close()
}}
```

Comment: use tex.sprint() then, to get rid of the trailing endline character :)

Comment: Not yet. I am running tl 2009 and I think luatex is a bit dated.

Comment: @Taco: I can't see a difference between `tex.print` and `tex.sprint` (both don't have a space). The manual states, that the last `tex.print()` does not have an `\endlinechar` inserted. As there is only one, it is also the last one. (Actually I always used `tex.sprint` and wonder why I didn't do so here.)

Comment: you are right. must be me getting old, I actually wrote that code ...